# Keeping collapsible div panel open when clicking on main content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I followed a quick tutorial online for adding a collapsible div panel to my site that opens and closes via a button.  However, once the panel is opened, clicking anywhere outside of the panel closes it.  My question is if there is anyway to keep the panel open until ONLY the user clicks the open/close button again?

Cheers,
Jquery noob

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -height: 75px;
    background: #ff99BD;
  z-index: 5;
}
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #34cbcb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -34px 0px 65px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -34px 0px 65px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  box-shadow: inset -34px 0px 65px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  z-index: 1;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #343434;
  z-index: 3;
}
  .slide-away {
  transform: translate(250px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(250px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(250px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(250px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(250px, 0);
}
button {
  color: #eee;
  background: #343434;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}
button:hover {
  color: #bbb;
  background: #565656;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hamburger"><button>Slide</button></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
$('button').click(function() {
$('#hamburger').toggleClass('slide-away');
$('#main').toggleClass('slide-away');
});
$('#main').click(function() {
$('#hamburger').removeClass('slide-away');
$('#main').removeClass('slide-away');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code? It is a bit of a guessing game atm.

Comment: Or at least a link to the site in question

Comment: Your code is what is at question here, but you haven't provided it. We can't diagnose nothing.

Comment: Thnx for backing me up :)

Comment: Sorry guys, added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove second click event

```
$('#main').click(function() {
    $('#hamburger').removeClass('slide-away');
    $('#main').removeClass('slide-away');
});
```

It does what you do not want to.

Comment: You're right, overlooked this. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It was just staring me in the face.. haha